# How can I stop certain apps from appearing in the Dash?

Tags: unity-dash, blacklist

I would like to hide all items that I don't need from appearing in App Lens.

For example: XTerm, File Roller and the Home Folder.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any app that you don't want displayed in the Dash it needs a line in it's .desktop, -
`NoDisplay=true`

If `NoDisplay=false` is there then in a text editor simply edit to `true`, if the line doesn't exist then add it

Most app's  .desktops will be found in /usr/share/applications & can be edited there in a root text editor. Alternately you can copy the .desktop to `~/.local/share/applications` & edit there instead with your normal (non root) text editor.

When copied there it is protected against updates & only applies locally to that user

Example in screen of adding line to debian-xterm.desktop

[image]

Comment: Any way to do this on a per-user basis? I'd like to blacklist the kids games from my Dash and the kids would like to blacklist my terminal emulators etc.

Comment: There is: http://askubuntu.com/questions/644384/hide-system-settings-applications-in-dash

Comment: I spent quite some time to figure out which name on the Dash corresponds to which name in *.desktop file. But this command came to the rescue: `dpkg -S desktop | grep imagemagick`. Replace `imagemagick` with what you are looking for.