# Hide System Settings Applications in Dash

Tags: unity, unity-dash, .desktop, system-settings

Is there any way to remove an application icon from the dash but keep it in the System Settings?

I find it useless to have them in the dash, and it really clutters the display there.. Accessing them from System Settings is the more logical way for me.

Specifically, I want to hide these icons:

[image]

From Here:

[image]

I tried editing the .desktop files, using various combinations of `NotShowIn`, `OnlyShowIn`, `NoDisplay=true`, etc. but it only hides the icon in BOTH places or in the System Settings only. Hiding them only in the Dash seems somewhat difficult.

**Edit:** To specify further: I want the single settings-icons that are visible in the System Settings window, hidden in the Unity Dash. That includes the applications "tab" - not only search results or recently-used applications.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I keep recent files from appearing in Unity?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29559/how-can-i-keep-recent-files-from-appearing-in-unity)

Comment: try simply to hide applications or folders from search so they do not appear in Unity dash search activity as stated in a link above. You can hide folders, applications etc.

Comment: I don't think this is related to that question. I am trying to hide actual .desktop entries, but keep them visible in the system settings window.
That other question is about recently used items that are to be hidden..
Also, I still want to be able to search the OTHER applications - not hide them altogether..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/gnome-control-center.desktop
```

Add this line:

```
NoDisplay=true
```

Save and exit and try now

[image]

#### Hide those apps

To remove all apps founded in the system settings you have to do such as above for each app. Let's start with Appearance:

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/gnome-background-panel.desktop
```

And add the line above then try.

Do this for other apps you want to hide

---

### Hide from Dash keeping those in System Settings

create the directory  `~/.local/share/applications` if you don't have it

```
mkdir  ~/.local/share/applications
```

Copy the `.desktop` files of what you want to hide, Doing example here for Appearance.

```
cp /usr/share/applications/gnome-control-center.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

giving permissions:

```
chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/gnome-control-center.desktop
```

Now edit and add "NODisplay"

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/gnome-control-center.desktop
```

Add the line

```
NoDisplay=true
```

Save and exit then logout and login.

The icon will removed from Dash search keeping available in system settings

Comment: As expected, this hides the icon "System Settings" from the dash. BUT the specific settings icons are still there. And thos are what I wanted to hide...

Comment: Then What? Is it what you need?

Comment: You have to do that for every app itself, i'll edit my answer

Comment: Which is what I tried - but NoDisplay also causes the icon to vanish from System Settings

Comment: As mentioned, I tried that. The icon vanishes on both places.

Comment: Ok now i understand what you want exactly, just some min and I'll try to give you valid answer

Comment: @founderio Check EDIT2 in my answer above

Comment: Brilliant, works like a charm!
(One could even think about automating that via a script, so changes from updates are reflected in the copies.. I'll see what I can do.)
Thanks!

Comment: Glad for you, have a nice time