# Hide specific applications from Dash

Tags: unity, unity-dash, .desktop

Is there a way to hide specific applications, for example Skype, from Dash?

If so, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/71240/how-to-remove-icons-shortcuts-from-unity-menu

Comment: @JacobVlijm There's no difference in hiding application shortcuts from Dash, whether the actual program was removed or not, because Dash deals with `.desktop` files, not programs themselves. You know this quite well.  Your answer really should have been on the duplicate.

Comment: @JacobVlijm  First of, removing `.desktop`  file doesn't remove application itself, besides they can be recreated.  Second, it's sufficient to rename it to hide ( `app.desktop.bak` for example ). Finally, same approach with editing the file can be applied in each case.  But if you're not satisfied with that question, there's a different one: http://askubuntu.com/q/644384/295286  Same answer as yours, same question. Verdict - still a duplicate

Comment: @Serg My turn to be surprised by your comment and explanation. You should never (advice to) remove a global .desktop file while the application is still installed. Recreate it? Do you know all the appropriate keywords that were used for language and all other options? Secondly, a bit weird to edit a .desktop file of an application that was removed. Not sure what is the point. I am pretty sure you very well know this is another question, requires another answer.

Comment: @Serg Your second one isn' t an exact dupe either, although it has the same solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Hiding an application from Dash

To hide *installed application(s)* (any) from Dash is very well possible.

1. Find the corresponding `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`
2. Copy the file to `~/.local/share/applications` . The local directory is hidden by default, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to toggle visability.
3. Open the file with (e.g.) `gedit`
4. Add the following line *before* the line (if it exists) `Actions=`, but below the first line:

   ```
    Hidden=true
   ```

Now log out and back in and you're done.

[image]

#### Note

Always first copy the `.desktop` file to `~/.local/share/applications` and edit the local one. The local one will then overrule the global one on re- login.

To undo, simply delete the local one.