# How can I remove ImageMagick from Ubuntu Unity Dash?

Tags: unity-dash, imagemagick

I don't need ImageMagick in the Dash but need to keep it as a installed program because many other programs depend on it.

**Question:**

Can I somehow hide the two icons or do I have to delete them?

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1075069#p1075069?

Comment: Also http://askubuntu.com/questions/70301/how-can-i-stop-certain-apps-from-appearing-in-the-dash/120618#120618

Answer (score 1):

Application entries are usually stored in `/usr/share/applications/`. You could view the contents of that folder, and then remove individual entries (or, a better solution, rename them to have a different extension). Here's an example (in this case I hide and unhide Chromium - the commands would be similar for ImageMagick).

To hide:

```
 cd /usr/share/applications
 sudo mv chromium-browser.desktop chromium-browser.desktop.hidden
```

And, to unhide:

```
 cd /usr/share/applications
 sudo mv chromium-browser.desktop.hidden chromium-browser.desktop
```

Hope this helps.